# Regex Expression to Limit Character Count in Google Form

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am trying to get a regular expression working in Google forms to limit the number of characters in a form.  I have tried a number of strings of code I have found online, but it does not seem to work.

The first string I tried was this, and it actually seemed to work for a bit but then stopped working:

```
[\w]{1,800}
```

The second I tried was this:

```
^\W*(\w+(\W+|$)){1,200}$
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why these won't work?  Also, should it be "regular expression", and then "contains" or "Matches?

Comment: did you want to match any character or only word character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know google forms, but a regex which can validate character count would be:

```
^.{0,200}$
```

- The bit `{0,200}` means *between 0 and 200*, so change that according to your needs.
- `.` is a placeholder for *any character*.
- `^` and `$` are begin and end of string anchors. They make sure the regex won't match in the middle of the string.